# Removing Vector from 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a 2D vector containing 96 blocks of 600 values, which is what I want.

I need to remove (blocks) that do not contain sufficient energy. I have managed to calculate the energy but do not know which way would be better in removing the (blocks) that do not contain enough energy.

In your opinions would it be better to create a temporary 2D vector, that pushed back the blocks that do contain enough energy and then delete the original vector from memory or...

Should I remove the blocks from the vector at that particular position?

Comment: Energy? Huh? If you ask whether it's better to create a new vector rather than deleting elements from the middle, I think the answer is probably yes.

Comment: Measure before optimize!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom

Comment: I suppose I would delete the blocks. But either way will work, so what does it matter?

Comment: @Beta Because I'm trying to be a better programmer and optimise my code / memory management ;)

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca This should be an answer.

Comment: @Phorce I'd say a better programmer produces readable, maintainable code and optimises when the result does not perform well enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have this:

```
typedef std::vector<value> Block;
typedef std::vector< Block > my2dVector;
```

and you have a function like this:

```
bool BlockHasInsufficientEnergy( Block const& vec );
```

and you want to remove the Blocks that do not have sufficient energy.

By remove, do you mean you want there to be fewer than 96 Blocks afterwards?  I will assume so.

Then the right way to do this is:

```
void RemoveLowEnergyBlocks( my2dVector& vec )
{
  my2dVector::iterator erase_after = std::remove_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), BlockHasInsufficientEnergy );
  vec.erase( erase_after, vec.end() );
}
```

the above can be done in one line, but by doing it in two what is going on should be more clear.

`remove_if` finds everything that passes the 3rd argument condition, and filters it out of the range.  It returns the point where the "trash" at the end of the `vector` lives.  We then erase the trash.  This is called the remove-erase idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd want to use linked list, or just set filtered-out items as NULL's, or mark them with bool member flag, or keep a separate vector of indexes of filtered items (if you have several filters at once this saves memory).

The solution vary on what are the constraints. Do you need random access? How much object copy takes? Etc.

Also you can take a look at the STL code (this is STL's vector, right?) and check if it does what you ask for - i.e. copying a vector data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, in part, on how you define better in this case. There may be advantages to either method, but it would be hard to know exactly what they are. Most likely, it is probably somewhat "better", in terms of memory and processing performance, to erase the exact positions you don't want from the vector instead of allocating an entirely new one.
It may be better still to consider using a deque or list for that purpose, since they may avoid large reallocations that the vector is likely to make as it tries to keep a contiguous segment of memory.