# Vector - Deleting blocks

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that checks the values of a vector and then deletes the blocks that do not have sufficient values in them to be considered.

```
vector<iniMatrix> Audio::filter(vector<iniMatrix>&blocks, double sumThres, double ZeroThres)
{
double totalSum = this->width * sumThres;
double totalZero = this->width * ZeroThres;

int currZero = 0;
int currsum = 0;

int prevsign = 0;

for(auto int i=0; (i < 96); i++)
{
    int currsign = zerocross(blocks[i]);
    double currSumOfBlocks = this->energy(blocks[i]);

    if(!totalSum > currSumOfBlocks || totalZero > currsign)
    {
        blocks[i].erase(blocks[i].begin()+blocks.size());
    }
}

return blocks;
}
```

It works up until the point of erasing the blocks, it's not deleting them because when I output `blocks.size()` it's still the same value as it was before, it should be smaller.

Anyone have any idea to why this is happening?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to delete? At the moment you're deleting the `blocks.size()`th element from `blocks[i]` which is an `iniMatrix`. This doesn't make much sense. What is an `iniMatrix`?

Comment: Are you sure you want `!totalSum > currSumOfBlocks`? You are using the  `!` operator on `totalSum`. Do you mean `!(totalSum > currSumOfBlocks)`? In other words, `totalSum <= currSumOfBlocks`.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `erase`?

Comment: Have you considered defining a predicate object with your conditions and using [`remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/)

Comment: @sftrabbit I want to remove the block, it doesn't surve a purpose anymore.. I want it so that the block size will go from 286 and will reduce to around 90 blocks because of the if statement..

Comment: @WhozCraig the remove_if confuses me, and, would mean I have to change a hell of a lot in code

Comment: @Phorce The reason you're not getting many answers is because it's hard to understand what you want. I've seen you posting similar questions over the last few days. Am I right in thinking you want the following: loop through each block, work out that block's `zerocross` and `energy`, once you get to a block with either `zerocross` or `energy` greater than `totalZero` and `totalSum`, delete all blocks from then onwards?

Comment: Also, `currSumOfBlocks` is named as though it should be a sum of values. At the moment it's just the result of `energy` for a single block. Did you mean something like `currSumOfBlocks += this->energy(blocks[i]);` (note the `+=`).

Comment: @sftrabbit Hey! I know, I've asked a lot of questions regarding this (I am learning this and more advanced concepts of C++)! Ok, so basically, it's signal processing.. "totalSum", "totalZero" act as threshold values, and, I have a 2D vectors containing blocks and for each of these blocks, I calculate the total energy (summation of blocks) as well as the number of times each of the values cross zero, from this, I need to remove the blocks that DO NOT contain the sufficient data so then I am left with the blocks that do contain the Phonemes so I can try and identify what someone is saying!

Comment: @Phorce Your vector is actually 1D, not 2D. I assume each element in the vector is a 2D matrix, right? So one of these matrices a "block"? If so, do you just want to remove the "blocks" that have energy greater than `totalSum` or crossed zero more than `totalZero` times?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19554/discussion-between-sftrabbit-and-phorce)

Comment: it would be *immensely* easier to understand your end-goal if you annotated the code a little better, and **please** post at least the class definition of **`iniMatrix`**, which was requested at least once above.

Comment: @sftrabbit Hello, sorry I was tidying up. I posted in the chat room :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Vector from 2D vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348839/removing-vector-from-2d-vector)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the i-th element you should do this:

```
blocks.erase(blocks.begin()+i);
```